Emulating a Windows x86_64 program on an ARM64 system
I'm making a physics engine in C++ and SFML on a Raspberry Pi. I don't get a better computer with an x86 processor for budget reasons. As of current, the engine is in a usable state, with features you would expect from a physics engine. So, I decided to release it. So I make a repository on GitHub, however I also want prebuilt binaries aswell,
for the commonly used platforms. The main problem is however as C++ is compiled, I can only compile it for Arm64, as I'm using a 64 bit port of Ubuntu. So, I went onto the web, and compiled it online. However, as I'm using Arm64, I can't test the program to see if it even works. I'm aware of tools such as WINE, and Box86, however I can't find out how to use them in unison to run the program. So is there any way of doing this? Or perhaps there's some package made to do this by itself?
